# Wordpress weird behaviour on comments

Tags: posts, comments

Every time I make link in one of my posts (post B) to other post (A), The post A gets a comment that it's content is a section of Post(B) that contains the title of the link I've made.
As an example if I publish a post like this :

> ........Hello as I told you in my [postA][1] some other text here....
>
> [1]: https://zanganli.ir?post=b

In the postA I get a comment like the following :

> ..told you in my postA..

And the author of this weird comment is Title of Post B !!!

Comment: That's called trackbacks. You can disable it - first go to Settings > Discussion and turn them off, but that only turns them off for new content. You then need to turn them off for all existing posts - you should be able to find an article with the mysql statement to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much , I've not heard of it till now , As I'm new here I'm limited and can't  vote your comment up , So please turn your comment into response with some short description about the trackbacks , So I'd be able to choose your text as an accepted answer .

Comment: By the way , Is it good to have this trackbacks from SEO point of view or not?